# Is it possible for a creature to be Mythic without being Legendary?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

Is it ever possible for a creature to be considered Mythic without being Legendary?

Is there an example of such a creature?

Answer (score 8):

#### All seventeen published Mythic monsters have Legendary Actions.

Of the published examples, all Mythic monsters are also legendary: the Tromokratis, Hythonia, and Arasta from *Mythic Odysseys of Theros* and the Dullahan from *Van Richten’s Guide to Ravenloft*, and the the thirteen Mythic dragons published in *Fizban's Treasury of Dragons*. [This search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=f&filter-is-mythic=t&filter-has-lair=) on DND Beyond will yield a Mythic creature without Legendary Actions if such a creature is ever published.

#### As a DM designing monsters, you can do what you want.

There’s no rule to stop you from implementing the Mythic mechanics without also having legendary actions. You can do as you like when designing monsters

Answer (score 3):

### A Mythic creature does not require Legendary actions, but this might affect the challenge and reward for the creature.

While there is nothing that requires this to be true, Mythic creatures are typically expected to be a challenge (and XP reward) equal to fighting two of the same creature at once.

The mythic creature's Legendary actions, especially the additional options available after the creature uses its Mythic action, help to maintain this level of challenge. This is necessary because there is actually only one creature in the battle, and the action economy limits the threat of a single opponent.

The Dullahan, for example, initially has up to 5 CR 10 attacks: 2 from Multiattack, and 3 from its Legendary actions.
After it uses its Mythic action, the Dullahan has up to 5 CR 10 attacks and 6 CR 1/2 attacks. The Dullahan retains it usual attacks, but now has summoned 3 Death's Heads which can attack once each and one can attack as part of each of the Dullahan's Legendary attack actions.

The other published mythic creatures also have similar abilities that increase their number of attacks or add an area effect ability.

A similar effect, that does not use Legendary actions, could be accomplished by some of the following options:

- Increase the number of attacks granted by the creature's Multiattack ability to 1.5 times normal (2 to 3, 4 to 6, etc.).
- Add a Recharge 4-6 ability that is expected to affect 2 targets or allows an existing single target ability to target two creatures.
- Increase the recharge rate of an ability that affects multiple targets from Recharge 5-6 to Recharge 4-6.